# Setting condition on just 1 timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to make it so when a certain condition is met on the 5 minute timeframe and other non-timeframe-specific conditions are met it allows for a long signal to generate on any timeframe. I thought this would be relatively easy to figure out but it's been a task. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: I was able to get the 200sma part to work as intended. The only piece I'm missing is below. I need these elements to also be referenced from the 5 minute, but I have found that once I turn them into arrays the results look different than before, even on the 5 minute timeframe itself:

```
leftBars = input(15, title='Left Bars ')
rightBars = input(15, title='Right Bars')

highUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
lowUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)[1])

short = ta.ema(volume, 5)
long = ta.ema(volume, 10)
osc = 100 * (short - long) / long
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an expression from a lower timeframe, you'll need to use the `request.security_lower_tf()` which will return an `array`.

For example, if you are on a 15 min timeframe and wishes to get the results of the 200 sma on the 5 min timeframe, you can use:

```
sma200fiveMinute = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "5", ta.sma(close, 200))
```

This will return an `array` which in this case will have a maximum of 3 elements (three 5 min bars, if existed).

You can then use any array function you want. For example, to check if 15 `close` is lower than lowest value of 200 small 5 min bars inside it, you can use:

```
longCond = close < array.min(sma200fiveMinute)
```

Comment: For example, I want the long condition when on the 15min to only be possible when price is below the 200sma on the 5min. Does your suggestion work for that?

Comment: No. I've edited my question to answer this issue

Comment: Thank you! I added an update to the post